# named_scope and substings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, substring, named-scope

I have a named_scope in rails that finds episodes by there directors given name

```
  named_scope :director_given, lambda { |dr| {:joins => :director, :conditions => ['given = ?', dr]} }
```

It works great but I would like it to also work on substrings one the name. e.g. instead of having to search for 'Lucy' you could just search 'Lu'.

P.S.
I also have another named scope which does exactly the same thing but on the directors last name. It there a way to combine the two?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
named_scope :director_given, lambda { |dr| {:joins => :director, :conditions => ['given LIKE ?', "%#{dr}%"]} }
```

Second question:

```
named_scope :director_given, lambda { |dr| {:joins => :director, :conditions => ['first_name LIKE ? OR second_name LIKE ?', "%#{dr}%", "%#{dr}%"]} }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but when  try to use it in the console i get this error:         

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "%": syntax error: SELECT "episodes".* FROM "episodes"   INNER JOIN "people" ON "people".id = "episodes".director_id AND  ("people"."type" = 'Director' )  WHERE (given = %'Lucy'%)           

I tried changing the = to LIKE but I just get the same error

Comment: Just a matter of style:
  named_scope :director_given, lambda { |dr| {:joins => :director, :conditions => ['first_name LIKE :dr OR second_name LIKE :dr', :dr => "%#{dr}%"]} }

It is trivial in this example but it can become handy if you have several params used several times each.